# What is the simplest way to stream from an iOS device to a Wowza server?

Tags: ios, udp, rtsp, rtmp, wowza

I have tried to use LiVu and Broadcast Me, but it does not work smoothly with what I am trying to do. I need to live stream audio/video from the iPhone to our servers (while saving locally).

I have tried to implement a RTSP UDP stream but it is proving to be more of a challenge than we initially thought. 
RTSP/UDP is preferred, but whatever gets the stream to the servers in a timely fashion will work.

Any advice or framework suggestions would really help. Have already looked at iOS-RTMP-Library but its too expensive for us to use at this point.

Answer (score 0):

I don’t know about your budget, but you might check [ANGL lib](http://angl.tv/lib/) which worked fine for us on RTMP.

Comment: Thanks for the link, I haven't seen that before. It's not much cheaper than some of the other libraries I've seen, but it looks like it would do the trick (We got this sorted out by using a custom h.264 encoder library from an independent C developer)